# HttpClient not able to get returned results

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I’m new with HttpClient and Web API so I’m sure I’m missing something obvious to others. I’m trying to call a 3rd party Web API with a list of new Employees. The API is supposed to return JSON with information about the employees that were uploaded. This is going to be a console app that will be run once a night. There is no requirement for this to run Async.

I’m trying to follow along with these articles.
 http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
and
http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/07/03/Building-Out-a-Clean-REST-ful-WebApi-Service-with-a-Minimal-WebApi-Project.aspx

What’s not working is the following code to try to get the API results into an array or list. When I run it in Debug it gives me an exception “One or more errors occurred.” which doesn’t give me a lot to go on.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            AddEmployeeResult employeeResults =  response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AddEmployeeResult>().Result;
                        }
```

The vendor gave me this as an example of what should be returned.

```
[{"EmployeeNumber":"22449","SuccessfullyAdded":true,"Existing":false,"Comments":"App UserId:  6037"},{"EmployeeNumber":"379844","SuccessfullyAdded":true,"Existing":false,"Comments":" App UserId:  6038"},{"EmployeeNumber":"23718","SuccessfullyAdded":true,"Existing":false,"Comments":" App UserId ps:  6039"}]
```

I created a class in my console app to match what is supposed to be returned from the API.

```
class AddEmployeeResult
    {
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public bool SuccessfullyAdded { get; set; }
        public bool Existing { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code I’m trying.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UploadNewEmployee();    
}

public static void UploadNewEmployee()
        {
            string serviceURI = "https://services.website.com/api/employees/upload";
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.Credentials = credentials;
            clientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;



            //***  Get the Employee Data  ***
            List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
            try
            {
                lstEmployee = DataManager.GetEmployees();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Error while getting data. | {0} | Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }



            //***  Process users if there is data.  ***
            if (lstEmployee != null && lstEmployee.Count > 0)
            {
                logger.Info("Employee count: " + lstEmployee.Count);
                logger.Debug("Web API Uri: " + serviceURI);

                try
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceURI, lstEmployee).Result;

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            AddEmployeeResult employeeResults =  response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AddEmployeeResult>().Result;
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error("Error posting to Web API. | {0} | Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                logger.Info("No records found.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does changing the problematic code to `AddEmployeeResult employeeResults =  response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<AddEmployeeResult>>().Result;` works?

Comment: That doesn't compile and gives an error that basically says that it can't convert a type List<AddEmployeeResult> to AddEmployeeResult. Earlier I had tried the following with the same issue. List<AddEmployeeResult> employeeResults = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AddEmployeeResult>().Result;

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... a bit typo on my previous comment, it should'v been: `List<AddEmployeeResult> employeeResults = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<AddEmployeeResult>>().Result;`...

Comment: Cool. I think that might work. Let me do some more testing and I'll get back if that worked or not.

Comment: Thanks! that looks like it's going to work.